# Plugin to save and execute code in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, chrome, plug-in

I'm looking for a Chrome plugin that allows me to save scripts and execute them as if they were being run from the Console window.

There are occasions when I write a small script to do some laborious task on a website. I run these scripts from the Console. For example:

- Trigger downloads sequentially from a site
- Edit some known selected text to convert it from markdown to HTML.

I would like to be able to save these scripts and easily re-execute them - ideally from something like a right-click menu.

Comment: You don't need a plugin, you can simply use the existing bookmark feature and save JavaScript code as the bookmark URL. Using it that way is often called bookmarklet.

Answer (score 1):

Install a user script manager, e.g. the [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) or Tampermonkey plugins, and check out their script-repositories such as [Greasyfork.org](https://greasyfork.org/en).

For example, I use the "all [Heise forum] comments on one page" script, and some IMDB enhancements.

AFAIK, these Userscript Managers don't rely on the browser console though.